# SSL Certificate Error when trying to do command-line registration with pypi

Tags: python

The error message:

```
Macinbu:nester majibu$ python3 setup.py register
running register
running check
Registering nester to https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
Server response (500): <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1051)>
```

I'm on OSX 10.13.6 and trying to follow along in the Heads First Python book, but stuck at this command-line registration part.

Python 2.7.10 is preinstalled on this system, but I downloaded and installed the latest python (3.7.1) as per the book's instructions.

I didn't have a pypirc file in my home directory so I had one created:

```
[distutils]
Index-servers = 
    pypi


[pypi]
repository = https://pypi.python.org/pypi
username = <myUsername>
password = <myPassword>
```

Which is nice since I don't have to enter my credentials anymore, but it made no difference in regards to the original error I'm getting.

Some online searching prompted me to check my version of OpenSSL and pip:

```
Macinbu:nester majibu$ openssl
OpenSSL> version
LibreSSL 2.2.7

Macinbu:nester majibu$ pip -V
-bash: pip: command not found
```

So I tried installing pip:

```
Macinbu:nester majibu$ curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py --user admin
Enter host password for user 'admin':
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-  0 1622k    0 10543    0     0  54701      0  0:00:3 74 1622k   74 1215k    0     0  1018k      0  0:00:0100 1622k  100 1622k    0     0   995k      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:--  994k
```

but I get the same error from bash indication that pip isn't installed.

Can anyone offer some advice on how to proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Found a script in my python3 application folder called Install Certificates.command which resolved the issue when I ran it.